# Django form with checkbox is always False

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I'm looking to create a Django form with a checkbox.Irrespective of weather I check or uncheck the box,it is not detected in POST request.Here is the code of the template-

```
<form action="annotate_page" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

      <input id="repeat" type="checkbox" >
                <label for="repeat">Repeat Sentence?</label>


      <br>

      <button type="submit">Next</button><br>

 </form>
```

Here is my forms.py-

```
from django import forms

class AnnotateForm(forms.Form):
    repeat=forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Here is my views logic-

```
if request.method=="POST":

    form = AnnotateForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)#prints only csrf_token in Query_dict
        print(form.cleaned_data["repeat"])#Always false
```

Irrespective of weather the checkbox is checked or not,the print statement always gives False.

I know there are questions similar,but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: In the form definition, the checkbox is named `repeat`.  But in your html template, the checkbox has no name at all!  (The id is `repeat`, but that's not the same thing.)

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the form fields in html anyway?  Use `{{ form.as_p }}` and Django will draw the form for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="annotate_page" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

      <input id="repeat" name="something" type="checkbox" >
                <label for="repeat">Repeat Sentence?</label>


      <br>

      <button type="submit">Next</button><br>

 </form>
```

and in view

```
if request.method=="POST":

    form = AnnotateForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)#prints only csrf_token in Query_dict
        print(form.cleaned_data["something"])#Always false
```

you need to give a name in the input field or else it wont be captured

Answer (score 0):

I was just having a related problem. I am creating a products form and during the use of the page the form can get pre-loaded via AJAX calls, and I was calling -- Using Jquery -- and my returned object was called data and inventory was the boolean I was interested in.

```
$("#edit-product-form").find("#id_inventory").val(data.inventory)
```

But what it actually needed was

```
$("edit-product-form").find("#id_inventory").prop("checked", true).val(data.inventory)
```

This way the checkbox is properly ticked (or unticked) and it still has the val set which is what is being read when it is submitted.

I also added an event that whenever I select the checkbox it changes the value to "true" or "false" respectively to keep the Django and Form gods happy.